# SQLCMD: Prompt for Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

Coming from an Oracle background, Oracle's SQLPlus would let you indicate a variable.  If the variable wasn't set, you'd be prompted to provide a value.

I'm using SQLCMD, using the $([var_name]) syntax.  In SSMS SQLCMD mode, I get:

> A fatal scripting error occurred.
>   Variable tbl_name is not defined.

...for trying to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $(tbl_name)
```

Does SQLCMD provide the same functionality as SQLPlus?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the code that you're using to call SQLCMD?

Comment: @Tom H.: I'm only testing it via the SQLCMD mode ATM.  My point is, I've seen how to supply the variables, but want to know if SQLCMD supports user interaction like SQLPlus does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLCMD does not support prompting for missing variable names. However, you can use SSMS in SQLCMD mode. Dunno how you're error was caused, but this works for me:

```
:setvar table "sys.tables"

SELECT * FROM $(table);
```

Comment: SQLCMD does not support GUI behavior like SQLPlus. Maybe have a look at SQL-PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool "SQLS*Plus" which is an SQL*Plus for SQL Server. Works with SQL Server 2000/2005 and 2008

Very flexible with data formatting (set lines size, pagesize, etc), variables (&, &&), spool, etc - light years better than isql, osql or sqlcmd

I downloaded SQLS*Plus from http://www.memfix.com