# declare variable by user in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to get input from a user for a variable?

For an example:
How do i get the firstname of a user to use it in my script to select it from my employee table.

I now how i declare a variable but not how to get it typed in by the user of the script

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT @YourVariable = FirstName
  FROM Employee
  WHERE Id = @SomeId
```

You can use sqlcmd http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms162773.aspx, so you can specify variables in command line

sqlcmd  -iyourscript.sql -v yourvar=yourvalue

and in script

```
 SELECT @YourVariable = FirstName
  FROM Employee
  WHERE Id = ${yourvar}
```

Comment: In this way i can select a firstname into @yourvariable.
But i am looking for a direct input from the user 
without using  a table

Comment: @Harm, What is mean 'direct input from user' in your context?

Comment: It means that the user who is running the script has to use the keybord to type in his firstname followed by enter.

Harm

Comment: I'm still not sure that will do what the OP wants? According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302225/sqlcmd-prompt-for-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like what you're asking with stored procedures.  Start them like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NameOfStoredProcedure]
(
   @cTableName      varchar(75),    -- name of the table
   @iTopLevelId         int = 0     -- Id parameter
)
AS
etc
```

Then when executing the stored procedure from Management Studio a dialog box will appear requesting the parameters.

Here's a walkthrough of the process: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1375

Comment: Hi I used the following:
CREATE PROCEDURE testing
( 
   @cTableName      varchar(75),    -- name of the table 
   @iTopLevelId         int = 0     -- Id parameter 
) 
AS 
print @cTableName 
print @iToplevelId
 
EXECUTE testing

But i only get the folowing error message:Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure testing, Line 0
Procedure or Function 'testing' expects parameter '@cTableName', which was not supplied.


What is going wrong?

Harm

Comment: @Harm. Instead of 'EXECUTE Testing', right click the stored procedure and select Execute

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error.
Is it possible that I need other right in Sql Server

Comment: @Harm. Weird, I'm not sure. I added an edit which describes the process.